# Failed to load fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My code somehow fails to load the fxml file. I have checked the path to the file and it is correct. Am I missing something? I know that I can use SceneBuilder to design my GUI and add the functionality with separate controller files.

JAVA CODE:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main4 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane page = (StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main4.class.getResource("/home/emil/code/javaGUI/src/sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("FXML is Simple");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

FXML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get a resource going from the root of your filesystem?

Comment: I am trying to give the exact path to my fxml file

Comment: I believe the path in the JVM is different than your filesystem once the code is ran. At least by going through the resource manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use the absolute path from source code directory rather than full file system path.

For example
if your package for the java source file is com.learnjavafx. Then file name should like /com/learnjavafx/sample.fxml.

But for your case, simply use sample.fxml because source code is not part of any specific package.

Comment: Figured it out it was a path problem indeed